# Disabling and reenabling submit button with cross browser compatibility in mind

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, submit

As another attempt to prevent bot spam comments on my site, I want to disable the submit button by default and let the user click the checkbox to enable it.

Here is my code:

```
<label>
    <span class="notbot">
        <input type="checkbox" class="acceptance" value="1" name="iaccept">
    </span> I'm not a bot!
</label>

<input type="submit" value="Post Comment" id="submit" name="submit">
```

[image]

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KVjzB/3/).

My question is, how can I do this using either Javascript or jQuery with cross browser compatibility in mind? I have come across various solutions with each having their issues.

Ideally a solution where if the user does not have JS enabled, then the button will not be disabled... If you choose to answer, please provide code example and update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KVjzB/3/).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution that leaves the submit button enabled when javascript is disabled, and works in most browsers:

```
$('#submit').prop('disabled', true);

$('.acceptance').on('change', function() {
    $('#submit').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KVjzB/4/)

Comment: Please define *most* browsers, compatibility is essential in this case.

Comment: The disabled property is supported in all major browsers for form elements like a button, except maybe in IE5 and below ?

Comment: Alse note that robots won't have "javascript enabled", so this does nothing other than annoy your users IMO.

Comment: Thank you for your input. So I suppose that the solution would be to make it server-side...?

Comment: A bot will most likely retrive the HTML, try and figure out the names and values of your form elements, and send a POST or GET request directly, it has no means of actually filling out anything and clicking a button, so disabling the button, hiding it, or anything else done with javascript really doesn't help much. You need something to look for on the serverside when the form has submitted, that you can check to see if it was an actual user or not, and that's why most websites have silly questions or ask you to type in some numbers etc. as only a real user would get the questions right.

Answer (score 0):

1. You add disabled propety in input `<input type="submit" value="Post Comment" id="submit" name="submit" disabled="disabled"/>`
2. use jquery script:

   $(document).ready(function(){

   $(".acceptance").bind("click", function(){

   ```
   if($(this).prop('checked')==true){ 

       $("#submit").removeAttr('disabled')   

   }

   else{

       $("#submit").prop('disabled', 'disabled'); 

   }
   ```

   });

});

This is [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ilialezhava/KVjzB/18/)

> Blockquote

:

Answer (score 0):

Pure Javascript example: I am changing the input type of the submit button to preserve the look and feel of the forum page

```
<form id="mainform" method="post" action="Default.aspx">
    <label>
        <span class="notbot">
            <input type="checkbox" class="acceptance" value="1" name="iaccept" />
        </span> I'm not a bot!
    </label>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Post Comment" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
    var iaccept_chkbox = document.getElementsByName("iaccept");

    if (iaccept_chkbox != null && iaccept_chkbox.length == 1) {
        submit.type = "button";
        iaccept_chkbox[0].onclick = function () {
            if (iaccept_chkbox[0].checked == true) {
                submit.type = "submit";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bbdEH/

Comment: Interesting approach, what happens if the user has Javascript disabled?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Since the default input type in the html markup is "submit", if Javascript is disabled, the comment will get posted.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson However, reading adeneo's comment in the previous answer, I believe, changing input type to "button" {not in the above code} by default might leave the bots wondering how the POST will be made; but then the human users will have to be compelled into enabling Javascript to make a POST.

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
        <label>
        <span class="notbot">
            <input type="checkbox" id="acceptance" value="1" name="iaccept"/>
        </span> I'm not a bot!
    </label>

    <input type="submit" value="Post Comment" id="submit" name="submit" disabled="disabled"/>
```

JQUERY

```
                    $("#acceptance").click(
                function() {
                $("#submit").attr("disabled", null);                        
                }
             );
```

Comment: What's the difference between your answer and the other one posted?